# How to set list view to full width?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I have an activity with a autocomplete textview, a add button and a list view that pops up when user is typing

[image]

In xml:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/locationButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:minWidth="46dip"
    android:onClick="getLocation"
    android:text="@string/icon_map_marker" />

<AutoCompleteTextView
    android:id="@+id/autocomplete_city"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:dropDownVerticalOffset="0.2dp"
    android:hint="@string/city_hint"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/locationButton"
    android:layout_alignTop="@id/locationButton"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/locationButton"/>
```

The problem is that the listview, that is created by the autocomplete process has the same width as the autocomplete text-view. However it should have full width, including the width of the button (see image). Any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html#attr_android:dropDownWidth

Setting

```
android:dropDownWidth="match_parent"
```

on the autocomplete textview solves the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Delete those aligns in AutoCompleteTextView with locationButton and then try to resize it to full width.

Answer (score 0):

Create the listLiew under another layout, do something like:

```
<LinearLayout>
    android:width="fill_parent"
    android:height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    <LinearLayout>
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        ...
        <AutoCompleteTextView> ... </AutoCompleteTextView>
        <Button> ... </Button>
    </LinearLayout>
    <ListView>
        ...
        android:width="fill_parent"
        android:height="fill_parent"
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Hope this helps (:

Answer (score 0):

use this layout. I tried and checked. this is helpful.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="100">
<AutoCompleteTextView
    android:id="@+id/autocomplete_city"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="70"
    android:dropDownVerticalOffset="0.2dp"
    android:hint="city_hint"
    android:inputType="text"/>

 <Button
    android:id="@+id/locationButton"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="30"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minWidth="46dip"
    android:onClick="getLocation"
    android:text="icon" />

 </LinearLayout>
 <ListView 
     android:id="@+id/listview"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent">
 </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I cannot declare the listview in xml because it is autogenerated by autocomplete textview as a popup